# 301 redirect a URL query parameter value to an alternate capitalization?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, parameters, parameter-passing

Is there a friendly way to 301 redirect an all-caps URL parameter value to a `ucfirst` version of it?

E.g. starting with: `http://www.example.com/results?color=RED`

301 redirect to: `http://www.example.com/results?color=Red`

**TL;DR:**

The website in question uses "hybrid" URLS to display search results

A simplified example:

`http://www.example.com/Red-Widgets/search?color=Red`

Which is fine. But when the capitalization on the parameter value is bad, we get:

`http://www.example.com/RED-Widgets/search?color=RED`,

an undesirable URL.

(btw, this unfortunately has happened, resulting in an unknown number of incorrectly capitalized URLs being indexed in the Google search results)...

We have removed a source of possible user input that can produce mixed case parameter values, however the facts remain that:

- the damage is done, and
- we may not have found all of the reasons for this happening, and
- it's still possible that users could manually type in improper capitalization, share the URL, and get it indexed in Google
- it doesn't seem like this corrected source was necessarily responsible for the bad URLs showing up in Google

So, for all these reasons, I'd like to try correcting the parameter values via a 301 redirect, which will in turn, also correct the first portion of the URL (the "RED-Widgets" portion in the example).

Comment: Is the `Red-Widgets` part of the url an actual folder or part of a rewrite rule?

Comment: Yes, rewrite; thanks for asking :)